# mongodb aggregation match date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b63e593f033ab66fa25a142"),
    "percent_change_1h" : 0.37,
    "percent_change_24h" : -3.91,
    "percent_change_7d" : -7.08,
    "last_updated" : 1533273443,
    "created_at" : "2018-08-03 05:18:11",
    "updated_at" : "2018-08-03 05:18:11"
}
```

its have created_at date like this "2018-08-03 05:18:11"
but i can pass date in aggregation function like "2018-08-03" 
data not get in this match

I can not use $gte or $lte becouse get only given date data 
query is here

```
$date = "2018-08-15";

$filters = ['$match'=>[
    'quotes'=>$quotes,
    'created_at' => $date]
];

$join = ['$lookup'=>[
    'from' => "cryptocurrencies_list", 
    'localField'=> "crypto_list_id",
    'foreignField'=> "_id",
    'as'=>"listdata"]
];

$limits = ['$limit'=>10];
$query = $detailscollection->aggregate([$filters,$join,$limits]);
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: @anthony Winzlet question is query not return any data

Comment: what is `quotes` here? what is the type of `createdAt` field? what is your mongodb version?

Comment: sir my database entry like this
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b63e593f033ab66fa25a142"),
 "crypto_list_id" : ObjectId("5b63dfc1f033ab605c1bb2d2"),
 "rank" : 1,
 "quotes" : "USD",
 "percent_change_7d" : -7.08,
 "last_updated" : 1533273443,
 "created_at" : "2018-08-03 05:18:11",
 "updated_at" : "2018-08-03 05:18:11"
}

Comment: i don't set any type for createdAt or any other field. any suggestion for me

Comment: Ok great .... What is your mongodb version?

Comment: my mognodb version: 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
$detailscollection->aggregate([
  [
    '$addFields' => [
      'date' => [
        '$dateToString' => [
          'date' => [
            '$dateFromString' => [
              'dateString' => '$created_at',
              'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
            ]
          ],
          'format' => '%Y-%m-%d'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    '$match' => [
        'date' => $date, 'quotes' => $quotes
    ]
  ]
])
```